# Como puedo realizar triple count de una tabla sql

Tags: sql

hola estoy aprendiendo sql y me gustaria saber como puedo hacer un triple count de una misma tabla que tiene tres categorias bronce,plata,diamante entonces estaba tratando como esto:

```
SELECT COUNT(idAbono) AS BRONCE FROM socios WHERE idAbono=1
SELECT COUNT(idAbono) AS PLATA FROM socios WHERE idAbono=2
SELECT COUNT(idAbono) AS DIAMANTE FROM socios WHERE idAbono=3
```

pero obviamente no se puede entonces queria saber como poder contarlas en una misma tabla

Comment: revisa sobre group by... y listo.. vas a tener los tres valores ;)

Comment: gracias lo hice asi SELECT COUNT(socios.idAbono)AS CANTIDAD,abono.NombreSuscripcion
FROM abono,socios
WHERE socios.idAbono=abono.idAbono
GROUP BY NombreSuscripcion;

Comment: no se que tiene que ver ese query, que tiene dos tablas, con el que mostras arriba. Es mas, tu query usa una forma de join que esta obsoleta hace mas de 15 años.. yo trataria de evitarla...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una suma condicionada, mediante `CASE`

```
Create table socios (idAbono int, col1 varchar(100));

Insert into socios
values
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(1,'a'),
(2,'a'),
(2,'a'),
(2,'a'),
(3,'a'),
(3,'a');
```

La solución:

```
Select COUNT(CASE WHEN idAbono = 1 THEN 1 END) AS BRONCE
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN idAbono = 2 THEN 1 END) AS PLATA 
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN idAbono = 3 THEN 1 END) AS DIAMANTE 
FROM SOCIOS;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: y porque no un group by? y de paso aprende ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si la información está en dos tablas, puedes hacer uso de `INNER JOIN` para mostrar información de ambas y contar por categoría usando `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(socios.idAbono) CANTIDAD, abono.NombreSuscripcion SUSCRIPCION
FROM socios 
INNER JOIN abono ON socios.idAbono = abono.idAbono
GROUP BY abono.NombreSuscripcion;
```